# How to Find, cut, paste and erase with VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I am new on VBA and i dont know almost nothing.
I've been trying a code to find a value entered in a inputbox "CXRG", find on sheet "ESTOQUEV" cut all the line and paste on sheet "SAIDA" (down from another values) and erase the blank line from "ESTOQUEV"

Someone could help me?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Enter()

linha = Worksheets("SAIDA").Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Worksheets("SAIDA").Cells(linha, 1) = CXOS.Value

Worksheets("SAIDA").Cells(linha, 2) = CXRG.Value

CXOS.Text = ""
CXRG.Text = ""

SendKeys "{TAB}", True    ' Envia TAB para pular par o inicio.

Call refresh.Macro8
End Sub
```

Comment: tis code is my actual code without the tryes

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you posted a picture/sample of your excel doc. You're description makes significantly more sense to you than to us. However, while learning VBA... using 'Record Macro' and doing things, and then studying what it produces is very helpful learning common actions.

Answer (score 0):

you have to try this code (run just `findAndPast()`)

```
Sub findAndPast()

Dim shttoFind As Worksheet
Dim shttoPast As Worksheet
Dim LastRowOffind As Long
Dim inBox As String
Dim cell As Range


Set shttoFind = Worksheets("ESTOQUEV")
Set shttoPast = Worksheets("SAIDA")

    Call Find_Last
    LastRowOffind = shttoPast.Cells(shttoPast.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
    shttoPast.Activate
    shttoPast.Cells(LastRowOffind, 1).PasteSpecial
    shttoFind.Activate
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub

Sub Find_Last()
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    FindString = InputBox("Enter a Search value")
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("ESTOQUEV").Range("A:C")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(1), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```